# How to download and save excel file using UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I need to download and save excel to a specific location using UFT.

Step 1: Click on hyperlink as seen below

[image]

Step 2: Save the downloaded excel as shown below.
[image]

Can you please advice on how to automate this scenario using uft?

Comment: Why do you have to click it? Why can't you right click the link and use Save Target As?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know UFT's web support can't handle such cases. This may be a case where UFT's image-based automation ([aka Insight](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/252430)) can be used.

You can use Insight to identify the required buttons if UFT doesn't recognise them as native `WinButton`s.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to apply a workaround of my own to manage the saving of files from this setup.  Here's the code I used:

```
If Browser("AFBHome").WinObject("Notification").Exist(6) Then
    LOG_Write "Notification received - click Save dropdown to get file."
    Browser("AFBHome").WinObject("Notification").WinButton("SaveDropdown").Click micNoCoordinate,micNoCoordinate,micRightBtn
    Browser("AFBHome").WinObject("Notification").WinButton("SaveDropdown").Click
    Wait 0,500 ' Allow the dropdown to render
    Browser("AFBHome").WinObject("Notification").WinButton("SaveDropdown").Type "a"
    Dialog("Save As").Activate
    Wait 0,500
    LOG_Write "Getting file from AFB: " & Dialog("Save As").WinEdit("FileName").GetROProperty("text")
    Dialog("Save As").WinEdit("FileName").SetSelection 0,Len(Dialog("Save As").WinEdit("FileName").GetROProperty("text"))
    Dialog("Save As").WinEdit("FileName").Type sSaveLocation & sFilename
    LOG_Write "Attempting to save export file as " & sSaveLocation & sFilename 
    Dialog("Save As").WinButton("Save").Click
End If
```

I had to learn the Notification Bar into the OR as a WinObject, and the SaveDropdown object is attached to the down arrow on the end.  I also had to use the `.SetSelection` and `.Type` methods rather than the normal `.Set` as the `SaveAs` dialog would end up saving the file to whatever was originally specified rather than the desired path and filename.

You can ignore the `LOG_Write` statements, as they are a custom function I use to track progress through my scripts.